# How to get SOAP response data?

Tags: objective-c, xml, serialization, soap

This is the `XML` response back from webservice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:OrientalServices1">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:Get_CategoryResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:responseGetCategoryByID[11]">
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">國內</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">2</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">財經</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">3</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">社會</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">4</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">國際</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">10</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">龍門陣</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">11</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">言論</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">6</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">名家</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">8</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">娛樂</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">5</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">體育</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">7</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">專題</name>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:responseGetCategoryByID">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">9</id>
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">特輯</name>
</item>
</return>
</ns1:Get_CategoryResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In this `XML`, I got 11 items in an array. How can I deserialize it and get the item one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XML parser.

There is support for a couple of methods in Cocoa - but since you've asked such a general question, all I can do is provide a general answer.

There is an [Introduction to Event Driven XML Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) on the Apple Developer site